# Google Friend Connect - Meaning of URLs

Tags: google-friend-connect

I would like to know the meaning of the URL's provided by google for its Friend Connect.

For example, in the FCAUTH, the user details can be grabbed by sending a request to the following link and a JSON encoded string will be returned

> http://www.google.com/friendconnect/api/people/@viewer/@self?fcauth=

Also for getting user activites, I came across a link as below

> http://www.google.com/friendconnect/api/activities/@owner/@friends/@app?fcauth=

What if I change the @owner to @me or @viewer , what would be the meaning and would it be valid?

Example, if i change it as

> http://www.google.com/friendconnect/api/activities/@me/@friends/@app?fcauth=
>
> http://www.google.com/friendconnect/api/activities/@viewer/@friends/@app?fcauth=

Also, could some one suggest me where can I get the User Profile URL for the user using the same method as above?

Thankx guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankx guys but I found the answer by myself. I thought of posting it here so that it might help others.

Its available in brief in the Opensocial website

http://www.opensocial.org/Technical-Resources/opensocial-spec-v081/restful-protocol

Hope it helps some